Can I use the Nadaraya–Watson estimator to estimate conditional expectation of stochastic processes?
I want to estimate the following conditional expectation
$$
E\left[ Y(t,\beta)  \mid X=x  \right],
$$
where $X$ and $Y$ are continuous random variables.
I want to use the Nadaraya–Watson estimator to estimate
$$
\hat{E}\left[ Y(t,\beta)  \mid X=x  \right]=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nY_i(t,\beta)K_h(x-X_i)}{\sum_{i=1}^nK_h(x-X_i)}.
$$
Is it true?
And under some conditions if it has uniformly convergence properties?
$$
\sup_{t, \beta,x}\left|\hat{E}\left[ Y(t,\beta)  \mid X=x  \right]-E\left[ Y(t,\beta)  \mid X=x  \right]\right|\rightarrow 0 \quad a.s.
$$

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
